# Is it safe for a Muslim to visit Israel nowadays?

Tags: safety, israel, islam

Is it safe for a Muslim to visit Israel nowadays? I got different answers for my question every time I ask. Can somebody with real experience help?

Comment: This is not an question that can be objectively answered. You got different answers every time because it's subjective.  I for example would be happy to go there, while my best friend wouldn't.  If you can clarify an objective means for this, then please, do flag it to be reopened, but as it stands currently it's a very subjective question and will be closed.

Comment: @MarkMayo, but the author has not asked if it is happily for a muslim to visit Israel, but is it safe. Safety is, I think, easy to define for everyone using common sense, as not being victim of a criminal activity.

Comment: @lechlukasz How would you answer it objectively? A lot of people said Egypt was unsafe during the riots etc, but tour companies still ran and had zero problems. In fact I had friends praising how welcome the locals made them feel, and that they felt safer than in London.  Even safety is subjective.  Tourists often feel safe going to Soweto in South Africa, but almost none of the South Africans would go there out of fear for their safety - highest crime rate area in the country!

Comment: @lechlukasz indeed, as Albert said, everyone he's asked has given him a different opinion, showing quite well that it's subjective.

Comment: @MarkMayo: I think "Do muslims want to visit Israel" can't be answered objectively as you say, but the question asks specifically about safety, and I would certainly hope that countries implement objective safety for all their visitors rather than something subjective! In the face of such questions our best sources are statistics. And the best kind of statistics to avoid bias on such a topic would come from multiple fields. I don't know how easy such stats are to come by but the site claims to be for experts so hopefully some expert can find something.

Comment: @MarkMayo: your arguments could be used to close all safety questions so far and ban the topic as inherently impossible to answer; likewise for plenty of other topics too. I don't think we should try to bury "hot" questions because they can attract flames. We can look for travel advisories issued by muslim countries about Israel, statements on the topic issued by the Israeli government, and independent organizations that could be involved in muslim tourism in Israel. There's certainly plenty of reasons for muslims to want to go! I think you rushed to close. I vote to reopen.

Comment: This is a tad vague. What parts of Israel are you (or your friend) wanting to visit? Are you worried about violence from the Israeli government, settlers, or from other Muslims? (I don't think being Muslim will reduce the risk of the latter) Or about traffic accidents?

Comment: I think the question needs a more precise definition of *safe*. Safety is both objective *and* subjective. People may feel unsafe, even though actual threats are quite low. The latter might very well apply to Muslims visiting Israel (or Jews visiting Iran).

Comment: @gerrit And to a person suffering from paranoid delusions even a padded room will be scary, so let's get the clarification.  Until then I think that this question should be closed as not constructive.

Comment: Dear friends, my concern about safety specifically is about extremism (from any side, I mean).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because general safety questions are off-topic, per https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3314/asking-a-good-safety-question

Answer (score 30):

Israel is quite a safe country. However, due to its particular geopolitical situation, there can be surprises. Travel to some regions should be avoided, such as the immediate surroundings of the Gaza Strip and the surroundings of the Lebanese border. Due to the war in Syria, there might be some trouble in the Golan Heights. If that's the case, the region will be controlled by the army and you will probably not be allowed to enter it. Have a look at your favourite travel advice page. As an example, [here you have the FCO's page on Israel and the Occupied Palestinian Territories](http://www.fco.gov.uk/en/travel-and-living-abroad/travel-advice-by-country/middle-east-north-africa/israel-occupied). Note that the roads are quite dangerous ... that's a real risk. The odds are much higher that you will be hurt in car crash than in a terrorist attack ...

Being a Muslim does not change this. Note that [according to an official source](http://www.cbs.gov.il/www/statistical/isr_pop_eng.pdf), 17.1% of the population are Muslims. There are also 1.6% Druzes, but they are quite localized (near Haifa and in the Golan).

Just go ahead and enjoy. Israel is an interesting country!

Answer (score 13):

Even in [turbulent times (2014)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_Israel%E2%80%93Gaza_conflict) I think Israel is a relatively safe country for Muslims. Safer than some other countries in the region. Some things to keep in mind while in the country:

- Avoid demonstrations, both in Israel and even more in the West Bank.
- Display of Islamic clothing or objects can lead to significantly more trouble with authorities and with Jewish people who are standing firmly behind the IDF.
- It is recommended to keep your passport on you, especially if you have a darker skin.

Crossing the border requires some more attention.

First of all, there are many countries that don't allow their citizens to go to Israel ([this map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Israeli_citizens) is an indication). Israel might still let you in but in this case it's advisable to first contact the Israeli authorities, ideally through a local business or organization that can sponsor your stay in the country.

Second, even as a citizen from a country [with visa-free access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Israel), with an Arabic name you can expect significantly more questioning when entering Israel.

Answer (score 2):

Around 1.5 million people or 20 percent of the [Israeli population](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Israel#Ethnic_and_religious_groups) is Arabic and most Israeli Arabs are Muslim, so another Muslim visiting from abroad would be pretty much unnoticed as far as locals are concerned. You might get extra attention from the bureaucrats at the airport, but once you leave Ben-Gurion the whole country is your oyster.

Relax and enjoy your vacation.

Answer (score 1):

There are many Muslims living and working in Israel.

This is anecdotal, but I traveled to Israel from Abu Dhabi with heaps of stamps (Yemen, Tunisia, etc) from predominately Muslim countries in my Passport.  With an Arabic name, you might be subject to uncomfortable questioning, but you will be safe.

I'd recommend not walking around in traditional dress, however, even though it is legal.